# how to add html elements on top of thumbnail image

Tags: css

I have a list of thumbnail images in a gallery and I was wondering how i would make something like this?

[image]

The only way i see it possible in my understanding is to make the thumbnail as a background image inside a div and have those elements be displayed on top of it. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Absolute positioning would be another option.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably achieve something like this using a wrapper div around the image with a div containing your overlay stuff as a sibling of the image:-

```
<div class='image'>
  <img src='' />
  <div class='image__overlay'></div>
</div>
```

Then your CSS would be something like this:-

```
.image {
  position: relative;
}
.image__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

You could hide the overlay with a `display: none` and only make it display on :hover of the div.image if that's what you were aiming to achieve.

Comment: I made a sample, the mouse leave wont work but it should do thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/wBcYF/31/

Comment: You can do this with CSS (which is what I was meaning to suggest in my answer): http://jsfiddle.net/drmonkeyninja/wBcYF/34/